# Adding comments to a list item

Tags: 2013, list, comments

I'm trying to implement an ideas form in my SharePoint Page for the team that I work in and I've created the site and the list with no problems but I'm having some issues trying to implement comments.

I would like something where anyone can comment on any item added to the list.

Comment: Can everyone add to the list, or do you need people who can only read the list to be able to comment?

Answer (score 2):

it might not be exactly what you had in mind, but you could always just use a Multiple lines of text field with 'Append Changes to Existing Text' on. Version history will keep it so that you can see who added what comment. This is the simplest way to accomplish this. This of course assumes that permissions are not restricted on individual list items.

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented same concept for our internal Idea Board solution. 
We have a multi line textbox field to store the comments in JSON object format.  The comment object will take "Date","User", "comment". This is a custom solution using JSOM.

I can help you further if you are looking same kind of solution.

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice JavaScript-only solution from spjsblog.com that you could give a try:
http://spjsblog.com/2014/03/04/commentbox-for-sharepoint-2010-and-2013/

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it in SharePoint (Append-Only-Comments) in the out of the box columns which keeps the old comments too.
follow below link for more understanding
https://chuvash.eu/2012/04/02/add-comments-column-to-your-sharepoint-list/[enter link description here](https://chuvash.eu/2012/04/02/add-comments-column-to-your-sharepoint-list/)

Also you can achieve this by using CSR in SharePOint list

http://letsdosharepoint.com/2015/08/13/how-to-add-read-more-link-in-sharepoint-list-using-csr/

There is another way using call out function in sharepoint

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/05/09/sharepoint-2013-callout-popup-tutorial/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24058.sharepoint-2013-callout.aspx

Comment: I was checking out the first URL you posted, and it's for SharePoint 2013 - Do you know how this can be done in 2013?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed an open graph Yammer thread into the item detail page; this is a cool solution that means they don't have to go 'edit' every time users want to comment on a list item; or indeed have to edit the item.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
short answer: you can't easily add comments to lists other than discussion boards.

Comment: So retarded you can't have comments on a list item in SharePoint. WTH Microsoft it's 2019 OMG.